# WindowsPhone app and GoogleMaps limits

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone, google-maps-mobile

My goal is to write a windows phone free app (with some ads) with milions of google maps requests per day. This request will come form thousands of independent users (free of any charge).

However, the problem is google maps API limits. For simple things, like getting maps or geocoding - no any API key is required. However if I search for places (e.g. Pizza in London or Cinema, Paris or Doctor AnyCityHere) - than 'places API' is accessed. It is limited for 100k requests per day per API KEY (not per user) so if my app will be succesfull it will stop working very soon each day.

According to https://developers.google.com/places/uplift - I can use "Places Library..." rather than "Places API web service" - in order not to use API key, and make limits counts for each user, not entire App. The problem is, that this alternative solution is a JavaScript library, and probably can't be used in WindowsPhone App, am I right?

So the question is: can anyone tell me how to give WindowsPhone users a reliable google maps solution, that makes places searach requests limit for single user, not for enitire app?

For now there is no point to write succesfull google maps client for WindowsPhone because getting success means you either stuck because API requests limit, or you have to pay google for this, am I right? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nokia Maps which is based on the powerfull maps of Navteq

[Maps and navigation for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)